# In linux how to replace a sub pattern inside a pattern in a file

Tags: string, sed, regexp-replace

I want to change a file, *read_write.c*'s content

```
SYSCALL_DEFINE1(lchown, const char __user *, filename, uid_t, user)
SYSCALL_DEFINE2(open, const char __user *, filename, int)
```

to

```
SYSCALL_DEFINE1(lchown, const char __user *, filename, uid_t, user)
SYSCALL_DEFINE2(open, const unsigned char __user*, filename, int)
```

i.e. I only want to change the argument inside the `SYSCALL_DEFINE2` but not that's inside `SYSCALL_DEFINE1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU sed:

```
sed '/SYSCALL_DEFINE2(/,/)/{s/const char __user \*/const unsigned char __user\*/}' file
```

From row which contains `SYSCALL_DEFINE2(` to row which contains `)` this replaces `const char __user *` with `const unsigned char __user*`.

Output:

```
SYSCALL_DEFINE1(lchown, const char __user *, filename, uid_t, user)
SYSCALL_DEFINE2(open, const unsigned char __user*, filename, int)
```

---

Take a look at `man sed` and search for `addresses`.